# How to validate if lambda expression has result

Tags: c#, attributes, lambda

I'm new in using lambda expression sorry for a dumb question. Anyway consider this statement:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = methodInfos.Where(k => k.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DLMethodAttribute), false).Length > 0).Single();
```

My question is how can to identity if the predicate part has a result, considering methodinfos does not have any member having an attribute. I've got an error message telling, ***"Sequence contains no elements"***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a potential for `Single` to fail because of no elements, use `SingleOrDefault`. It will return the single matching element, if one exists, or the default value for the type, which will be `null` for reference types (classes). You will need to check against null prior to using the result.

```
var methodInfo = methodInfos.Where(k => predicate(k)).SingleOrDefault();
if (methodInfo != null)
{
     // use result
}
```

Another method pair to have in your bag is `First` and `FirstOrDefault`. Like `Single`, they will return a matching element. Unlike `Single`, they will not throw an exception if *more* than one element exists that matches. Keep these in mind if you ever have a sequence that you need *a* matching element from, not necessarily *the only* matching element.

Answer (score 0):

There is Any() Extension method that it can check for you.

```
if (methodInfos.Where(k => predicate(k)).Any())
```

Or--

```
if (methodInfos.Any(k => predicate(k)))
```